# How to set secondary screen as default for mirror mode?

Tags: root-access, screen, system, remote-access, screen-mirroring

I have a rooted LG phone running android 12. There is screen+ feature in LG like samsung dex that gets activated only when connected with usb to monitor. But when I connect via wifi to any display device for screen mirroring, only main android screen is shown.  I want to mirror only secondary screen i.e. screen+ desktop. Ticking force desktop mode in developer options did not help.

Is there any way to set screen+ desktop as a default screen for mirroring by making changes in android system settings ?

Comment: Do you want to mirror the second screen while it is shown via USB on an external monitor if without a monitor connected via USB?

Comment: I want to mirror the second screen which is screen+ desktop via wifi to any casting device without the need of usb to hdmi cable.